# Is there clear instruction on migrating to office graph from EWS Impersonation?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

My company currently offer an Exchange Calendar integration to our customer by using EWS. Each customer's IT department will create an Admin Account that has the Impersonation right and provide it to us by entering into the UI tool. When we update the calendar event of their employee's calendar, we use that account login to Impersonate the employee.

With the deprecation of Basic Auth access for EWS in October 13th, 2020. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/

I can't get a clear answer on how we can migrate.

In general, do we register as an App (daemon), then each client company need to grant permission to us? How do we connect to their Exchange server? With what?

Answer (score 0):

My company also has similar kind of app - booking using Outlook calender. We are currently working on a migration for our Office 365 customers.
The change in EWS is for Office 365/Exchange Online only.

If you are serving Exchange Online customers you can continue to use EWS for a while, but you will need to migrate from Basic Auth to OAuth. You can find a good description on how to implement OAuth with EWS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)

To become "future-proof" you should also migrate from EWS to Microsoft Graph.